# How to print include table border show in the printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem to show the border in the printing. Below is my coding:

`button`

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Print</button>
```

`Table`

```html
 <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped dataTable">
```

`Javascript`

```html
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var printme = document.getElementById('table');
    var wme = window.open("","","width=900,height=700");
    wme.document.write(printme.outerHTML);
    wme.document.close();
    wme.focus();
    wme.print();
    wme.close();
})
```

My printing output like below, no table border to show in the printing:

[image: Output 2]

My HTML page:

[image: output 3]
Hope someone can help me to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the styles defined by those classes are carried over to your new window, but that's just a guess. Keep the window open so you can check how the table actually looks like on this new window.

Comment: can you post a screenshot on how this table looks in the html page (not in the print screen)

Comment: @rbansal Screenshot updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is not being retained in new window while printing. You can get pass some CSS to the new window in your document.write() method

like

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;'
        '}' +
        '</style>'
    var printme = document.getElementById('table');
    var printDoc = css + printme.outerHTML;    // note this added css
    var wme = window.open("","","width=900,height=700");
    wme.document.write(printDoc);
    wme.document.close();
    wme.focus();
    wme.print();
    wme.close();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

issue:

when you render the HTML page it has access to all the bootstrap styles (that you either installed or are using a cdn), when you generate the print page you are creating a new html document and are only placing the html and not the styles.

potential solution:

add the cdn for bootstrap styles into the document that you are creating for printing like this:
`wme.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">')`

let me know if that worked!